# Is it possible to assign the Windows 7 detect resolution function to a hotkey?

Tags: hotkeys, kvm-switch, resolution

I recently got a new 27" monitor that runs at 1920 x 1080.  It's shared, via a KVM switch, between my wife's computer and mine.  It has a bit of a problem switching between computers now, that it didn't have on my old 22" which ran at 1680 x 1050.  When I make the switch, it often fails to display in the correct resolution.  Clicking the KVM switch a few times usually gets it right, but sometimes it's stubborn and I have to right-click on the desktop, click Screen resolution, then click the Detect button.

It's not annoying enough (yet) that I'm going to get a new KVM switch, but it would be nice if I could assign that Detect button to a hotkey, so that when this happens, I can quickly fix it.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Windows 7, you can use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> hot key to switch between multimonitor and single monitor. It is essentially what you are already doing with the KVM switch. This might get the desired result you're looking for.